# How to keep the data of two Postgresql installations in sync

Tags: windows, postgresql

I work with a desktop computer an a laptop. I develop on both machines but only one at a time. When I start using my laptop I sync all its data with the data directory of the server: text, applications, etc. When I'm back I sync my laptop back to the server. This works fine.

I recently started to use Postgres (I'm a noob to databases at all) and I expect that things are not that simple in that region. How can I keep the data of two Postgres installations in sync given the way I am working (sync server with laptop, use laptop, sync laptop with server)? Is that as simple as copying the modified data over the existing data or should another scheme be adopted?

I am not sure whether it matters but on the desktop I use win7-64 and on the laptop win8-64. I am trying to get acquainted with linux on virtual machines so a solution that is platform independent is appreciated :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possibilies:

1. Filesystem level synchronization
   PostgreSQL stores all data in a data directory. The data directory is selected during installation. In my opinion the simplest solution is to stop PostgreSQL service on both computers and synchronize the data directories. Versions of PostgreSQL should be the same. You should copy the data directory from one computer to another. **Never try to synchronize in both directions!**.
2. [Create a backup of a source database and restore it on target server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html)
3. (Advanced)[Use proper replication solutions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html).

Comment: I have to find out about the first possibility, but I have flagged this answer as correct as it points to two other solutions with links. Thanks!